# How to connect Grails controller to a view?

Tags: grails, model-view-controller

I have the following project structure:

```
myapp/
    grails-app/
        controllers/
            myapp/
                WidgetController
                ...etc.
        views/
            widget.gsp
            ...etc.
        ...etc.
    ...etc.
```

I am trying to connect `widget.gsp` to a method inside `WidgetController`. Here's the controller:

```
class WidgetController {
    def index() {
        render (
            view: "widget",
            model: [
            ]
        )
    }
}
```

When I save and go to `http://localhost:9400/myapp/widget` I don't see any of the UI code in my `widget.gsp` being displayed. This makes me think that I haven't connected them correctly. What can I do to fix this and associate the controller with the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given your folder structure:

```
render view: "/widget", model: []
```

alternatively you can put your GSP into

```
    views/
        widget/
           widget.gsp
           ...etc.
```

and use your original code:

```
render view: "widget", model: []
```